# I am getting an error when trying to access a vector<string> element, info in text

Tags: c++, string, vector

This is my errorcode:

> error: 'class __gnu_debug_def::vector, std::allocator >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > >::std' has not been declared
>   compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

This code is just a generic one i made to produce the same error, but my original code is trying to do the `strings::vector::at(i)` action:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    std::string string;

    std::stringstream range1d;
    range1d.str( "Hello0,Hello1,Hello2,Hello3,Hello4,Hello5");

    while(std::getline(range1d,string,',')) {
             strings.push_back(string);

         }

         for(std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator i = strings.begin();  i != strings.end() ; ++i) {
             cout  << "at: " << strings.std::vector::at(i) << endl ;
         }
    return 0;
}
```

I am fairly new to C++ and while given the error code, i really don't know how i can resolve this. Have googled for some time. I found something about declaring typename or something, but i couldn't apply it so that it made sense.
Thank you for any help

Comment: `strings.std::vector::at(i)` won't work (you're using a template without specifying arguments). Just say `strings.at(someIndex);` `strings.std::vector<std::string>::at(someIndex)` would work, but it's overly verbose without a need.

Comment: Ye that makes sense. Long day, slow head :/  Thank you for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i` is an iterator, and all you need in order to get the value is to dereference it.

```
std::cout << "at: " << *i << std::endl;
```

The `at` member function takes an index.  That is, an integer indicating the position in the vector that the element you want is at.  You might use it in a loop that looked like this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i<strings.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << "at: " << strings.at(i) << std::endl;
}
```

In addition, you need to include the appropriate headers for all the facilities you use, namely `<vector>`, `<sstream>`, and `<string>`.  You also need to qualify `cout` and `endl` in the `std` namespace.

Comment: That solved it, thank you. I think my initial problem was: Fairly new to C++ :)